# Как в chart js на вертикальной оси добавить единицы измерения

Tags: диаграммы, график, chart.js

график выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а надо так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обведите, пожалуйста, место с отличием другим цветом, более хорошо видимым на тёмном фоне

Answer (score 0):

Я прошу прощения, это наверное не лучший ответ, но выбирая график под реакт, я так же столкнулся с похожими проблемами и вместо него взял этот: https://www.highcharts.com/
Highcharts мне показался ппц гибким. И плюс документации много, включая ответ на ваш вопрос. (Там это уже точно встроено)